# preg_replace_callback nao retorna valores

Tags: php, string

Esse meu código não esta retornando os valores `$owner` e `$mid` na função `make_user()` Porque?

```
preg_replace_callback('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])M([a-z0-9_]+)/i', function($matches, $owner, $mid) {
    return $this->mark_user($matches, $owner, $mid);
}, $text);
```

Comment: adicione um contexto maior a este código

Comment: Porque esta não seria a forma correta de passar estes valores, aonde está a declaração de $owner e $mid?

Comment: Pelo que vi, você tentou criar uma função anônima(lambda style) e dentro dela você chamou outra função, o que não faz sentido, poderia ter referenciado a própria função. Você precisa referenciar a função assim: function($matches) use($owner, $mid) etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo da função(Já que o usuário não postou todo o contexto da pergunta):

```
public function replace_variables( $subject, $otherVars ) { 
$linkPatterns = array( 
    '/(<a .*)href=(")([^"]*)"([^>]*)>/U', 
    "/(<a .*)href=(')([^']*)'([^>]*)>/U" 
); 

$callback = function( $matches ) use ( $otherVars ) { 
    $this->replace_callback($matches, $otherVars); 
}; 

return preg_replace_callback($this->patterns, $callback, $subject); 
}

public function replace_callback($matches, $otherVars) { 
    return $matches[1] . $otherVars['myVar']; 
}
```

fonte: http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php